# Whipped Cream Separates While Piping

Tags: baking, cream

When I pipe my cake for decorating, some have a complex design so I take at least an hour. But after a while, the whipped cream started separating in the bag. Is this because of the warmth of my hands?? I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: I don't know much about piping cream, but if you think this is the issue you could easily test it my not putting so much cream in the piping bag at once, keeping the reserve in the fridge.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an insulated piping bag with a disposable plastic piping bag inside?
Is the room hot?
Is the whipped cream over whipped?

To solve the heat problem, try folding a dissolved gelatin sheet into the whipped cream.

If the cream is over whipped it will start to look a bit grainy, as the fat starts to glob together as the fat turns to butter.

Comment: I didn't know they had insulated bags.  If it was just the heat of somone's hands, you could try cotton gloves or similar, but I suspect it's likely the whole heat of the room.

Comment: They are often used to pipe hot mashed potatoes. Alternately, wrap the bag in a cloth.

Comment: It’s already snowing here now so the whole house is pretty cold, but I’ll try using gelatin next time! And the cream was only whipped to soft peaks too.

Comment: Just pointing out some of us have hot, hot little hands. I need an insulated piping bag if it will keep my buttercream from melting. (I intentionally overfill my bags because the part I'm squeezing it going to melt within a minute or two no matter what.)

Answer (score 0):

I remember a pastry chef once explaining to me that if your pastry bag isn't totally clean and dry, any residual oils could "break" the cream, resulting in what you described.
We would use DIY parchment paper bags for this very reason.
And if the issue is indeed heat related just make up 2 bags and keep one in the refrigerator, switching back and forth between the two.